ThinkPad T460s fingerprint reader on Ubuntu 20.04?
I've been using Ubuntu for a bit, but I can't figure out how to add my Fingerprint reader to the login thing. Can someone help me out here? This is my first time ever using a fingerprint reader without Windows, or even using a laptop in general!
